# Lock a certain range in a file using `fcntl` and `F_OFD_SETLK`

Tags: c, linux, file

### Objective

I want to open a file multiple times, but each `fd` should be only allowed to write to a specific range.

#### Background

I have an EEPROM which contains multiple "partitions", where each partition holds different information.
I want to avoid that one partition overflows to a different one, or one partition can read other information and misinterpret them.

### My Problem

I wanted to use `fcntl` along with `F_OFD_SETLK` so that I can lock a specific range on each opened `fd`.
Locking works as intended and trying to lock an already locked range will result in `EAGAIN`, which is expected.

What is not so obvious for me is, that I can write to a range that is locked by a different `fd`.

### Question

Is it possible to lock a certain range in a file so that it is not writeable by a different opened fd?
If not, is there a different way to achieve my goal?

#### Code:

Link to onlinegdb: https://onlinegdb.com/ewE767rbu

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void ex(const char *what)
{
    perror(what);
    exit(1);
}

static void lock_range(int fd, off_t start, off_t len)
{
    struct flock ff = {
        .l_type = F_WRLCK,
        .l_whence = SEEK_SET,
        .l_start = start,
        .l_len = len,
    };

    if (fcntl(fd, F_OFD_SETLK, &ff) < 0)
        perror("fcntl");
}

static void write_at(int fd, const char *str, off_t offset)
{
    if (pwrite(fd, str, strlen(str), offset) < 0)
        perror("pwrite");
}

int main()
{
    int firstfd = open("/tmp/abc.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (firstfd < 0)
        ex("open");
    if (ftruncate(firstfd, 0x1000) < 0)
        ex("ftruncate");

    lock_range(firstfd, 0, 0x800);
    lock_range(firstfd, 0, 0x800); // check if I can aquire the lock multiple times

    int secondfd = open("/tmp/abc.txt", O_RDWR);
    if (secondfd < 0)
        ex("open");

    lock_range(secondfd, 0, 0x800); // this one fails on purpose
    lock_range(secondfd, 0x800, 0);

    lock_range(firstfd, 0x801, 1); // and this one fails on purpose

    write_at(firstfd, "hallo", 0);
    write_at(firstfd, "hallo", 0x900); // this should fail, but doesn't

    write_at(secondfd, "welt", 0); // this should fail, but doesn't
    write_at(secondfd, "welt", 0x900);

    close(firstfd);
    close(secondfd);

    system("hexdump -C /tmp/abc.txt"); // just for visualization
}
```

#### Output:

```
fcntl: Resource temporarily unavailable
fcntl: Resource temporarily unavailable
00000000  77 65 6c 74 6f 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |welto...........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000900  77 65 6c 74 6f 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |welto...........|
00000910  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00001000
```

Please note *`welto`* which is `hallo` overriden by `welt`. I expected `hallo` at `0x0` and `welt` at `0x900`.

Comment: These locks (like most POSIX/linux locks) are _advisory_. So, holding a given file region does _not_ prevent a `write`. All users of the files must _cooperate_. That is, _all_ users must do (e.g.) `lock(fd,start,len); writeat(fd,start,len,buf); unlock(fd,start,len);` atomically. But, even if you do that, you don't have a "transaction". You'd have to do: `lock ; read; modify data; write; unlock` Are you using [separate] processes or threads? I'm not sure I see the advantage of multiple fds pointing to different regions of the same file (particularly since you're using `pwrite`)

Answer (score 1):

Locks come in two flavours: mandatory locks, and advisory locks. These are advisory locks. This means they prevent others from obtaining a lock. Period. They don't prevent writes or any other form of modification.

> If not, is there a different way to achieve my goal?

Don't ignore failures to obtain a lock.